# Why the ssh error trying to log into orange pi running ubuntu core?

Tags: ssh, configuration, ubuntu-core

After configuring an Orange Pi Zero with Ubuntu Core it fails on attempts to ssh into it with the error in image.  I am using TerraTerm and pointed the private key file to the one created using for the account.  I assume that was the wrong thing to do?  The board otherwise does not log in.

[image]

Comment: I ripped out keys etc to clear out any errors, reburned the SD card etc.  I have tried generation a key with and without passphrase, I have tried using a cygwin console instead of terraterm.  All up, not looking good for me bothering with ubuntu.  I only meant to try it for the snaps but I now find I can do that on Debian.  No rush.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to relate to a couple of problems but the principle solution was:

**Do not create a ssh key that includes passphrases.**

This was not apparent from the instructions - one is expected to have priori knowledge.

And yes the Terraterm needs to point to the file that ssh-keygen creates.